# Running Django Server

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I need help tried to run server for Django and got this error, The included URLconf '<module 'myapp.urls' from 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Django Tutorial\myproject\myapp\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

for urls.py in myproject is:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

for myapp views.py is:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request): return HttpResponse('hello')
```

For myapp urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.index, name='index'), 
]
```

Comment: Have you tried using absolute import in the myapp urls.py instead of relative one? PEP8 recommends the use of absolute imports. So `from myapp import views` instead of `from . import views`.

Comment: Check your `settings.py` file. look at the `ROOT_URLCONF` variable. Is it using `myproject.urls`

Comment: Try running the command `python manage.py check` and see if Django provide more information and kindly share the full error traceback.

Comment: I tried all of the solutions its still not working.

Comment: instead now its showing this

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dobble/
Using the URLconf defined in mytask.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, dobble/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.